# how to get the data from a column based on name not the index number

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with column abc having values like below

```
[{note=Part 3 of 4; Total = $11,000, cost=2750, startDate=2021-11-01T05:00:00Z+0000}]
```

Now I want to extract data based on name,for example i want to extract cost and start date and create a new column.

Asking it to be working on name because the order of these values might change.

I have tried below line of code but due to change in the data order I am getting wrong data.

```
        df_mod = df_mod.withColumn('cost', split(df_mod['costs'], ',').getItem(1)) \
    .withColumn('costStartdate', split(df_mod['costs'], ',').getItem(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your data is **not** comma-separated, it just looks like that. You'll want to use [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) to find the correct content.